# How to flip horizontally all elements of a psd file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

I have designed a psd file which includes many elements in English, now I want to reproduce it in Persian language which is a right-to-left one so I need to flip whole the document horizontally. Normally I can flip each element by Edit>Transform>Flip Horizontal but this option is not active when I select several layers. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image > Image Rotation > Flip Canvas`

This will flip the entire document.

If you **don't** want to flip all layers, duplicate the layers you *do* want to flip to a new document, flip them, then move them back to the original document.

Alternatively, you can create a Smart Object of layers to flip. Open the smart object, flip the canvas, save, and close and the Smart object contents will be flipped.

Comment: Thanks you so much, great solution. Can you explain more about your alternative?

Comment: Smart Objects are sort of a separate document within the main document. So when you double-click to open a smart object, you get a new window for that (internal) document. It has its own canvas and you can alter it like any other main document. The difference is when you save and close, it will be updated in the enclosing psd file that contains the Smart Object.

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot.